# QtCreator with BlackBerry Z10

Tags: qt, gcc, qt-creator, blackberry-10, blackberry-ndk

I installed BlackBerry NDK including IDE and downloaded the SDK. Now, I already set up Qt-Creator 2.8.1, 2.8.0, 2.6.2... In every version there is another problem with the build settings. The most appropriate try was with 2.6.2 and manually setting up the BB10 integration.

BB10 NDK Version: 10.1 for Target 10.1.0.4633 armv7le-v7

Creator is always started with bbnk-env.bat called before.

**2.6.2:**

Compiler set to GCC with custom-arm-linux-generic-elf-32bit as proposed by https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/core/qt_porting_tools.html
(I do have a second compiler set to unix instead of linux)

QT-Version provided by Blackberry NDK, Qt 4.8.5 within %BBNDK%\host_10_1_0_238\win32\x86\usr\bin\qmake.exe.

Devices: BBZ10 is connected and accessible. QtCreator successfully connects and can use the debugToken.

*Now the problem is within the Kits*: Created a kit for BBZ10, having the bbZ10 Device, bbndk\target_10_1_0_4633\qnx6\armle-v7 as sysroot, compiler (set for linux), gdb to ntoarm-gdb.exe, QT-Version to configured 4.8.5. I can now try **any mkspec** it always gives me the error (translated from german)

> No mkspec found for given QT Version
>
> Für diese QT Version wurde keine mkspec gefunden
>   I think the mkspecs are set to compile to unix-target, while the 4.5qt supplied with the sdk requires to be linux target (where in reality target is QNX)

Somehow i can compile with this version, but first i am not sure if this creates a correct executable, even more i cannot deploy the executable, since QT-Creator does not create the bar-descriptor.xml file...

**2.8.1:**

Using the same setup as in 2.6 (after having 2.6 QT Version configured) i am able to get to the same error. *Using the "new" configuration system* under "BlackBerry" page in settings i cannot correctly set up NDK Path. Will always tell me (translated from german)

> Following problems were encountered during BB10 configuration:
>
> - No QT-Version found
> - No GCC compiler found
> - No GDB Debugger for BB10 Comiler found
> - No GDB Debugger for BB10 Simulator found

Has anyone successfully configured bb10 ndk to use with qt-creator (2.6/2.8.1) and encountered similar trouble?
How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved:**
After 24 hours trying, installing, reinstalling, editing, crying... I reinstalled complete NDK and QtCreator 2.8 and edited bbndk-env_10_1_0_4633.bat.

1. I removed every Variable from batch file and set it to corresponding values, e.g. replace every %BASE_DIR% with your acutal base-dir (i.e. D:\bbndk).
   For conveniance usage i craeted another batchfile, calling the bbndk-env batch and starting qt-creator.
2. Set Compiler, Qt-Version, Kits in Creator-Settings as described in https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/core/qt_porting_tools.html

Keep mkspecs line under Kits-tab empty

Thank You